# What does $:.push do in ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I found this in Gemspec file of [surveyor gem](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor/blob/master/surveyor.gemspec). What does the following line do?

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "surveyor/version"
```

Why does the `$:.push` thing do? To me it looks like its just `requires` the `../lib/surveyor/version` file. if so, can't I just replace that with following one line?

```
require File.expand_path('../lib/surveyor/version', __FILE__)
```

Are both these same thing? If not, then what the difference?

Comment: Just a side note: `$LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path ...` does the same and looks a bit less obfuscated, IMHO.

Comment: indeed, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Symbolhound.com is useful for searching syntax like this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$:` is Ruby's load path, so it's in fact adding the a subfolder `/lib` of a folder in which `__FILE__` resides to this array, so that other files from this gem can be `require`d.

Comment: Basically a shortcut of having to write the complete path. That explains it. Thanks!

Comment: @Gaurish: Not only that. The gem can assume that it is in the load path, in which it will fail to load if you require it by full path, without adding it to the load path.